# how to load a file into a mysql table for a particular column?

Tags: mysql

I need to load a file into mysql table for a particular column
I have a table cc with 2 columns name and points, I have to update only the points column, I have a txt called point.txt which has only the points,now I need to load the point.txt into the table cc for the particular column(pionts)
this command is for a whole table.

```
load data local infile '/path/point.txt' into table tablename;`
```

I need to load the data for a particulate column,

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You can either load both columns from a text file, or upload the file into a single row. What is what you want to do?

Comment: i have dynamic data for the points.txt so i have to update the points column for every 15 min, but the points.txt file contains only the points value and not the names. that's the problem here.

Comment: Do you have a scripting language you can use to manipulate the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the column names to load the data into. Take a look at the manual page for [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/point.txt'
INTO TABLE 'tablename'
(points)
```

Comment: when i use this command new set of rows get added,i need the data to be displayed besides the name

Comment: Of course new rows are added. That's what LOAD DATA does. If you want to import and update existing rows, you will need a key of some sort in the input file so mysql will know which row to update, and that's a whole different thing.

Answer (score -1):

I what i got from your question that you are looking to INSERT an entire file into a single column LOAD_FILE function is use for same as follows

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = LOAD_FILE('/path/yourfile.text')
```